# Student, Major and Course relationships in relational database

Tags: database

A student can enroll in many courses.
A course can have many students.
=> student and course have a n-n relationship

A student can have many majors.
A major can have many students.
=> student and major have a n-n relationship

A course can belong to many majors. (e.g.. MATH-125 belongs to both Mathematics and Computing science).
A major have many courses.
=> course and major have a n-n relationship.

Question:
I want to add a major table to the below database, but it will be Circular References if I link 3 tables (Course, Student and Major) together.

[Database](http://i866.photobucket.com/albums/ab225/chaocanha/Untitled-1_zps20ce6e65.jpg)

How I can model them without circular references with the rule that students who want to take a specific course, must be in the major which the course belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `CourseMajor` and `StudentMajor` tables instead.

CourseMajor will contain `CourseID` and `MajorID`.

StudentMajor will contain `StudentID` and `MajorID`.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. If I do that, it will be like http://i866.photobucket.com/albums/ab225/chaocanha/Untitled1_zps0948c374.jpg is it ok to have the big circle relationships? And how can I prevent students taking courses which are not in their majors?

Comment: The diagram looks fine.  You prevent students from taking courses which are not in their majors by JOINing the CourseMajor and StudentMajor tables by MajorID, and seeing if the StudentID is in the resulting record set.

Comment: So, when a student enrolls in a course, we will check whether or not this course belongs to the student's major. If not, we prevent him/her from inserting a new record to Transcript table. Thus, basically, we will do that by implementing a query. Is that right?

Comment: Thank you very much. By the way, that database above is from a textbook. I do not understand the  table "requires". in its E-R diagram (http://i866.photobucket.com/albums/ab225/chaocanha/Untitled2_zpse7c0bf88.jpg) , it is "prerequisite", it is also a course, and it is described as a recursive relationship. But the way it is modelled in the database is like weak entity. Table "Whenoffered" is an multi-valued attribute in E-R diagram. It means one course can be offered in Spring and Fall semesters and it is a 1-n relationship, but in the database, it is n-1 relationship.